# Share widget by pages in a QStackedWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to build a widget to display images like a slideshow using a `QStackedWidget` and a `QGridLayout`.

It would have arrows on the left and right sides to swipe between the images (change the pages of the QStackedWidget).

Is it possible to create these `<=` `=>` buttons only once and display them on all pages? or do I need to create them inside of each page of the `QStackedWidget`?

[image]

Comment: Why are you using a stacked widget? Just change the image url when you click the button and show a new image .

Comment: Because it will contain other widgets together the image

Comment: You should be more clear. Are you trying to make a widget for an image(such as a QLabel) overlap buttons, using the QGridLayout? That is an undocumented feature and should be avoided. You should implement a custom QLayout for that. Anyway, assuming you already did that, why not just making the QStackedWidget overlap buttons?

Comment: @relent95 `undocumented feature` what feature? i have no idea what you are talking about. `why not just making the QStackedWidget overlap buttons?` because QStackedWidget is inside of a Grid, the buttons should move together it.

Comment: `You should be more clear.` my question is if is possible to make a widget on one page visible on all other pages.

Comment: Adding multiple widgets to the same cell of QGridLayout is an undocumented feature. On making a widget on one page visible on other pages, QStackedWidget does not have that functionality(and it's unnecessary and unnatural to have that functionality). Anyway, you are trying to make a widget overlap with the buttons, right? Then just do what I said - let a layout(QGridLayout if you insist) contain the QStackedWidget and the buttons, and put widgets for images to QStackedWidget.